# AppiumServiceBuilder start method is failing - Cannot find module 'electron'

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, electron, appium

When I try to start the Appium server programmatically, I am running into the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'electron'
Require stack:
- C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\electron-settings\lib\settings.js
- C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\electron-settings\index.js
- C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\dist\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\electron-settings\lib\settings.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\electron-settings\\lib\\settings.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\electron-settings\\index.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\dist\\main.js'
  ]
}
```

I am new to Appium so I have no idea what this means. I tried `npm install --save-dev electron` but it didn't change anything.

This is what my code looks like:

```
public class TestInitiate {

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    static Properties props;
    AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
    AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void initiateServer(){
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"));
        builder.withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\dist\\main.js"));
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you install Appium using npm? To me it looks like you are trying to start the server through Appium Desktop install directory and Appium Desktop is an electron app

Comment: I can't remember, to be honest. Probably npm